# Prevent Unwanted Inserting Behaviour (Table Columns)

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how its possible to stop the following `HTML` `code` from

1. Inserting into the column of the table
2. Not show up as an image

The column is  VARCHAR inserted via text-box

```
'<img src="SOMEIMAGELOCATION.jpg" alt="STACKOVERFLOWRULES" style="width:69px;height:69px;">'
```

As expected I'm currently testing my points of entry where data is taken in , I guess somewhere in my query I need to prevent this?

Comment: You probably need to read up on `Injection` http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: okay I need to use param as far I see from that manual thanks

Comment: Using a param won't help. That's to prevent people from breaking your queries. You need an input sanitizer of some sort. Use htmlentities() to convert html into printable characters, and don't convert it back on outputting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to store HTML, you have to convert the input-data from a string containing HTML to one that doesn't. You have a few options.

If you just want everything to come out exactly as typed, without turning into html, use the htmlentities function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

If you just want to get rid of the HTML entirely and leave only plain text, use the striptags function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php